# Elfinder multiple users

Tags: elfinder

I would like to use my `$_SESSION` and show a folder in function of the user.

I try to exploit the system of Elfinder but I need some help.

My own html

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="client_infobanque">Ajouter un fichier</label>
            <a href="../Include/elFinder/elfinder.src.html" target="_blank">Lien vers les fichiers liés à mon client</a>
          </div>
```

connector.minimal.php

```php
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        // Items volume
        array(
            'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',           // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path'          => '../files/'.$_SESSION['Contact_id'],  // path to files (REQUIRED)
            'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/'.$_SESSION['Contact_id'], // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'trashHash'     => 't1_Lw',                     // elFinder's hash of trash folder
```

Thank you for advance guys. 
PS : I use the last version of Elfinder, findable on https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder

Answer (score 1):

Remember that session variables work only if you have session_start(); before any output at the top of your connector PHP.
Then, your idea is right, but I would do a better implementation. Assuming that you stored your "contact_id", something like the username, and it is the same name of the folder you prepared inside /files/. For example /files/pippo/ is the folder of the user "pippo". Also, you want a superadmin who has control of everything inside /files/, call it "god", at the top of the connector you put this code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if( $_SESSION['contact_id'] == 'god' ){
  $userpath = '../files/';
} else if( $_SESSION['contact_id'] != 'god' ) {
  $userpath = '../files/'. $_SESSION['contact_id'] . '/';
} else {
  die("Forbidden Access!"); 
}
```

Then you modify the paths with the new $userpath variable, so...

```
'path'          => $userpath,
'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/' . $userpath,
```

Then the trash folder, inside any user folder, also...

```
'path'          => $userpath . '.trash/',
'tmbURL'        => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/' . $userpath . '.trash/.tmb/',
```

Done.